# MAMP: local-environment … connecting to ftp won't work?

Tags: php, ftp, mamp

i love working with mamp ( i have the pro version).
i'm currently trying to connect to a ftp server and list the files up there. however the connection is successful but it won't list the files.

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $path);
```

returns bool(false)

however the script is working if i run it on my real webserver. is there maybe some preference i have to set to get it working locally as well?

regards

Comment: I am having the same issue. If I find anything I will post an answer.

Comment: I filed a ticket for this issue. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60143 vote on it if you are having the same problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have MAMP so I did a little testing using the first example in the php manual page for [`ftp_nlist`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php), and was getting the same error as you (`bool(false)`). Turns out, if using that code:

```
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

// output $contents
var_dump($contents);
```

and the login fails either because of a bad username or password, if will fail with the `bool(false)` message.

Better to do something that will give you better info as to where it failed (if it does fail):

```
// set up basic connection variables
$ftp_server='127.0.0.1';
$ftp_user_name='user';
$ftp_user_pass='pass';

//initiate connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);


// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass) or die ('login failed');

// get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".") or die ('could not get contents');

// output $contents
var_dump($contents);
```

I tested this and it works. Given the right credentials, it will log in and dump the dir. If the credentials are bad, it will `die` with a 'login failed' message. If the path is bad, it will `die` with a 'could not get contents' message; so at least if it does break down you'll have a better idea of where.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

`ftp_nlist()` can sometimes return false if you're behind a firewall. Try turning on passive mode with [`ftp_pasv()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php) directly after authenticating, like so:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($server_ip);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $username, $password);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $path);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue that resolves this. If you boot your Mac into 32 bit mode, it appears to be working. To boot your into 32 bit mode, hold down the 3 and the 2 on the keyboard when booting. I am able to get this function to work.

RESOLUTION:
I found the resolution for this.

> To solve do the following: add this to the php script:
>   var_dump(getenv(TMPDIR)); exit;
>
> Mine returned a strange tmp dir location or /var/folders
>
> Then I did: sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/folders
>
> Now it works as expected!